# Is gravel necessary for post hole drainage in sandy Florida soil?

Tags: drainage, fence, post, gravel, soil

I am installing 6’ vinyl privacy fence in FLORIDA.

I would like to think the sandy soil would drain well enough. The labor and cost of digging deeper holes and buying and delivering gravel doesn’t seem worth it.

Do I really need to add 6” of gravel to the bottom of the post holes for drainage?

Comment: Feel free to adapt to local conditions. Somehow I suspect the state has more than one soil profile, but if your local one does not seem to need additional drainage, don't. On the other hand, do pay attention to other local conditions such as wind, which might make you want longer posts set deeper than "average" advice.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to concern yourself with the gravel if sand is present at the bottom of the hole. It will drain. I imagine the reason for drainage is that if water got into the hollow post and froze, would ruin the post. You may not have a freezing problem there in Florida.

What I would recommend is adding a brick or something else like that so the post bears on that instead of sand. The sand may give way and allow the posts to settle more than you want over time.

Do give consideration for the high winds mentioned in an earlier comment.